# Using flexbox, how can I have a scroll bar for overflowing child?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am using flexbox. I have a parent div and 2 children. When the second child goes in the second row (for example in portrait mode) then I want it to have as maximum height the height of its parent and also have a scroll bar.

PS: In my example I simulate the 2 rows by having the widths of the children being more than the width of the parent.

```css
.dialog {
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.left {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.right {
  width: 400px;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: pink;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="dialog">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

Here's a codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-brook-9pw20y?file=/src/styles.css

Answer (score 0):

(excuse my english and spellings)

its prtty easy,

just give the right child a height of 100% and a max-height of 100% minus the height of the first child, use the calc() css function to subtract the height
like this,

```
  height: 100%;
  max-height: calc(100% - 300px) /*mind the space around the subtraction symbol*/
```

also use overflow: auto; instead of scroll, this will make the scroll bar show only when content is overflowing

```
.right {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100%; <-- height 100%m to match parent
  max-height: calc(100% - 300px); <-- set maximum height 100% minus the height of the first element,

  background-color: pink;
  overflow-y: auto; <-- overflow auto so the scrollbar can only show up then there is overflowing content
 }
```

please comment if you need me to clarify anything, or if i misunderstood what you wanted to do

```css
.dialog {
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.left {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

   .right {
      width: 400px;

      height: 100%;
      max-height: calc(100% - 300px);

      background-color: pink;
      overflow-y: auto; 
    }
```

```html
<div class="dialog">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: With your code I don't get any scroll bar in the pink box.

Comment: it shows up when the content of the pink box overflows, try adding a lot of staff in the pink box,